# Hide notification bell in status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can i hide the notification bell icon in the status bar at the bottom right in visual studio code.

I tried searching in the settings but cant find anything for this.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45612

Comment: As of v1.36 right-click on status bar to show/hide its elements.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45612), it is not possible to remove the bell.

If you want to hide the entire status bar:

Go to View -> Appearance -> Hide / Show status bar to hide the entire status bar.

Comment: I dont want to hide the entire status bar only the bell icon

Comment: See this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45612. It seems like we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Officially - no.

With this [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#overview) extension you can inject any `CSS`

```css
.statusbar-item[statusbar-entry-priority='-1000'] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to hide it only when there weren't notifications. In my case, I used [the custom css and JS loaded plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#overview) that @Alex mentioned, but with this css:

```css
[title="No Notifications"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```